# Reestablecer contraseña de usuario en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.2 y estoy intentando de hacer funcionar el envio de email para recuperar contraseñas...

Cabe destacar que use el comando ... ´´php artisan make:auth´´

Ahora bien...es importante que sepan que cambie el User.php que trae laravel por defecto por uno que yo mismo he creado se llama Usuario.php

El acceso de usuarios me funciona perfecto no tuve problemas con eso...pero cuando hago clic en el boton de reestablecer contraseña

[image: emailsend]

para ver el funcionamiento me encuentro con esta imagen.

[image: Error]

Ahora mi modelo esta bien porque tiene lo que necesita, tal como el modelo que crea Laravel por defecto.

```
class Usuario extends Authenticatable
```

El envio de email ya lo he implementado en la aplicacion usando `Mail::`  asi que no tengo mal configurado el envio de email pareciera que el problema fuera otra cosa....espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: bueno, el error indica la falta de un email que envie la contraseña. Fijate que en el .env tienes la opción para configurar un smtp con una direccion de correo que envie el email. Antes obviamente tambien verifica que el correo funcione bien. Luego lo agregas en tu desarrollo de laravel y haces la prueba.

Comment: La opcion de envio de correo ya la atengo configurada, recuerda que ya estoy usando la funciona Mail:: y envio correo sin problema...pero cuando quiero usar esta funciona automatica no me funciona.